# CLLocationManager delegate not called ios 11 (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Hey guys I'm new to iOS programming and I have been struggling to figure this out. My locationManager delegate is not being called. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit;
import MapKit;

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var mapView: MKMapView!;

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager();

    override func loadView() {
        // Create a map view
        mapView = MKMapView();

        // Set it as *the* view of this view controller
        view = mapView

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("MapViewController loaded its view.");
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true;

        let btnImage = UIImage(named: "mapview-track-user.png");

        //Tracking button creation code
        let trackButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton;
        trackButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 500, width: 60, height: 60);
        trackButton.setImage(btnImage, for: UIControlState.normal);
        trackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(centerMapOnUserButtonClicked), for: .touchDown);

        //Shadow for track user location button
        trackButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor;
        trackButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0);
        trackButton.layer.masksToBounds = false;
        trackButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
        trackButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9;

        mapView.addSubview(trackButton);
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        mapView.delegate = self;
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            print("Location servicese are enabled!");
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
            locationManager.startUpdatingHeading();
        }
        else {
            print("Location Services not endabled!");
        }
    }

    //Called upon clicking track user button in order to snap map to user
    @objc func centerMapOnUserButtonClicked() {
        self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.followWithHeading, animated: true);
        print("Track button clicked!");
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        let location = locations.last as! CLLocation
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
        region.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        print("*** locationManager Called! ***");
    }

}
```

I am trying to follow various guides online and get familiar with tracking users and eventually displaying other users on the map. Right now I am also slightly confused as to the uses of the CLLocationManager delegate vs. mapView.setUserTrackingMode when it comes to tracking a user in real time.

I have searched all around for a solution but have been completely stumped here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The map view call will produce temporary permission to location. Whereas the location manager will allow you to specify behavior more rigorously. Please be sure to add the appropriate line to your info.plist. In your case; add the middle entry from below and your location manager should start updating.

[image: info.plist]

Comment: I've already added all three keys (NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription, etc.) and yet it still isn't calling the delegate. It shows my location fine on the map but I believe that it because of .showUserLocationOnMap

Comment: Are you building for the simulator or the device?

Comment: I'm building it on my device and have simulated movement successfully through the debugger but can't seem to trigger the didUpdateLocations function. The other delegate functions such as didChangeAuthorization work just fine and I have followed Apple's guide on setting keys and location authorization. Really odd.

Comment: instead of these startUpdating calls, try calling locationManager.requestLocation()

Comment: I was able to get it to work by changing the `locations: [AnyObject]!` parameter to `locations: [CLLocation]` as outlined in the documentation. I should have read over it better the first time but lesson learned!